# Event listeners onclick()? - accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a series of accordions that activate using the following code:

```
$(function () {
        $(".specialreveal").hide();
        $('[href="#"]').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
        $(document).on("click", "a.biobutton", function () {

            var $currentSection = $(this).closest(".biowrapper").find(".specialreveal").toggle('slow').end();

            //If you want to hide all other `specialreveal` sections
         $(".biowrapper").not($currentSection).find(".specialreveal").hide('fast').end();



        });

    });
```

I'd like to scroll the accordion to the top when an element is clicked and am using this:

```
$( ".biowrapper" ).click(function() {
        $('html,body').delay( 1200 ).animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 800);

});
```

the problem am having is that, if an accordion tab above is open, and I click on the one below, the scroll to top is thrown off because, am assuming the math is calculated with TWO tabs open, so when one closes the top reference is wrong.

I've tried setting a delay(), trigger() and such but I can't seem to get it right.

I'd like to be able to scroll to top AFTER the previous tag closes and the new one opens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `offset().top` is calculated immediately then stored for later use by `animate`.

Just use a timer to delay the operation instead:

```
$( ".biowrapper" ).click(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 800);
    }, 1200);
});
```

*Ideally you would instead listen for the previous operation to end via an event on the accordion itself*

Comment: I tried, but it still messes it up. Maybe cause the math is still calulated first with two tabs open, and only does it on delay...?

Comment: The example shown does the calculation in the callback (after 1200 milliseconds). Best you look into the second option (events on the accordion).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want your scroll to run on the [activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) event

> Triggered after a panel has been activated (after animation completes)

```
$(".biowrapper").accordion({
    activate: function(evt, ui) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 800);
    }
});
```

Comment: xcept an not using jquery .accordion..? would what still work?

Comment: @Deedub then why have you tagged the question `jquery` / `accordion`? Unless whatever library you are using also has an activate event then I'd say no...

Comment: Because, it is jquery, but just not using their accordion function, instead using toggle.